# AzureRM - Ubuntu VM created using uploaded VHD stuck waiting on boot prompt

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-resource-manager

I have an Ubuntu Server 17.10 VM in vCenter that I exported using Export-VApp, then used Microsoft's Virtual Machine Converter to create a VHD. Created an Azure RM Disk Image from that and spun up a VM, all of which seemed to go fine. My problem is that the New-AzureRMVM gets stuck in creating, and when I go to the boot diagnostics from the screenshot it is stuck on a "Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:". First, from what I gather is there really no way to get console access to my VM so that I can enter this? It won't get past creating so connect is greyed out and I can't SSH into it. Is my only option here to go back to the VM on vCenter and migrate the entire partition to a new partition without disk encryption, then redeploy? Is there any sort of startup file Azure accepts that could input this for me?

Comment: No, Azure does not provide console for VM. You could create VM from your VHD on Hyper and install necessary software package. Then upload VHD to Azure. Please check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/create-upload-vhd).

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here.Good Luck

Comment: @shellter My hope was that there was a command within Azure-Cmdlets that I was ignorant of. Given that doesn't appear to be the case (thank you Walter for the links) I'll get this moved to one of the other sites.